# HTML pages still accessible without login

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am building a site on Glitch.com for me and my friends. I already know HTML/CSS, and am learning JS.
Even though it's not that secure, I want the login system to be made out of JS since this project is just for fun and to improve my skills.

I currently have the login page with HTML/CSS, and wrote a few JS if statements for the login validation. I want the users who are logged in successfully to be redirected to another page, home.html.

However, I can still access home.html by just inserting /home.html to the end of the link, not requiring sign in. How do I fix this?

HTML code for login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Login for Access</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/login.css">
    <script src="/login.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    
    <h1>Login for Access</h1>
    <p id = "access-denied">Incorrect User ID/Password</p>
    <form id = "login-form">
      <label for="user_id">User ID:</label>
      <input type="number" id="user_id" name="user_id" required><br><br>
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" required><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value= "Submit" id = "login-submit">
    </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("access-denied");

loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user_id = loginForm.user_id.value;
    const password = loginForm.pwd.value;

    if (user_id === "id" && password === "pass") {
        window.location.href="home.html";
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

Sorry if anything is unclear. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could edit this for more clarity.

Comment: When you say "not that serious" do you mean you're willing to accept that anyone can trivially impersonate anyone else in your app, bypass any authorization checks, and do whatever they want, and you're okay with that?

Comment: I'm saying that it's just for fun and I am not going to share the link to anybody other than my friends.

Comment: Okay. Then if you don't want them to be able to utilize the home.html page via URL, then add some logic on that page that runs when the page first loads to check if they're authorized, and change the location to a page they're authorized to be on (or hide the page contents and show an Access Denied message). Just keep in mind anyone can bypass it if they want to, and it doesn't require special skills.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use client-side code to stop people accessing pages. Client-side code is ultimately under the console of the owner of the browser.

Authentication/Authorisation has to be done server-side.